# Changing output data for different cases in mileage calculator in Java

Tags: java, string, input, output

in this assignment, I am to calculate a reimbursement value based on mileage traveled.  If the mileage value is less than or equal to 0, i am supposed to output the mileage value and "*****" in place of the reimbursement value.

What I am having trouble with is getting it to print just the 5 stars.  I can get it to print the stars, but it is followed by a "0" and I need it to print just the stars.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Asgn6 {

    static Toolkit tools = new Toolkit(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Declare variables and define file names
    double mileage = 0.0;             // Amount of mileage traveled
  double reimbursement = 0.0;       // Amount of reimbursement for mileage
  int numValues = 0;                // Number of mileage values in input file

  final String INPUT_FILE  = ("Input.txt");
  final String OUTPUT_FILE = ("Output.txt");
  String heading1 = "Mileage Traveled";
  String heading2 = "Reimbursement";

  // Access the input/output files
    File inputDataFile = new File(INPUT_FILE);
    Scanner inputFile  = new Scanner(inputDataFile);
    FileWriter outputDataFile = new FileWriter(OUTPUT_FILE);
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(outputDataFile);
  System.out.println("Reading  file " + INPUT_FILE + "\r\n" +
                       "Creating file " + OUTPUT_FILE);

  // Display the results
  printHeading(heading1, heading2, outputFile); 

  // Read first number of file to determine number of values in file
  numValues = inputFile.nextInt();

  // Read input file and calculate reimbursement
  while (inputFile.hasNext()) { 
     mileage = inputFile.nextDouble();       
     if (mileage <= 0) {
        reimbursement = 0.0;
     }
     else if (mileage < 400) {
        reimbursement = 0.18 * mileage;
     }
     else if (mileage < 900) {
        reimbursement = 65 + 0.15 * (mileage - 400);
     }
     else if (mileage < 1300) {
        reimbursement = 115 + 0.12 * (mileage - 900);
     }
     else if (mileage < 1900) {
        reimbursement = 140 + 0.10 * (mileage - 1300);
     }
     else if (mileage < 2600) {
        reimbursement = 165 + 0.08 * (mileage - 1900);
     }
     else {
        reimbursement = 195 + 0.06 * (mileage - 2600);
     }
     summaryOutput(mileage, reimbursement, outputFile);

  } // end while loop

    inputFile.close();  // close the input file
    outputFile.close(); // close the output file

  System.exit(0);
   } // End main 

   // *********************************************************************

   // Methods Section

// Display output heading
public static void printHeading(String heading1, String heading2, 
                                PrintWriter outputFile) { 
  System.out.println();
  System.out.printf("%-10s\t %s %n", heading1, heading2);
  outputFile.printf("%-10s\t %s %n", heading1, heading2);
}// End printHeading

//**********************************************************************

// Display results summary
public static void summaryOutput(double mileage, double reimbursement, 
                                PrintWriter outputFile) {

  String noMileage = "*****";  // String to display stars for no 
                               // reimbursement value

  if (reimbursement > 0) {
     System.out.println(tools.leftPad(mileage, 8, "0.0") + 
                        tools.leftPad(reimbursement, 25, "0.00"));
     outputFile.println(tools.leftPad(mileage, 8, "0.0") + 
                        tools.leftPad(reimbursement, 25, "0.00"));
  } // End if
  else {
     System.out.println(tools.leftPad(mileage, 8, "0.0") + 
                        tools.leftPad(reimbursement, 25, noMileage));
     outputFile.println(tools.leftPad(mileage, 8, "0.0") + 
                        tools.leftPad(reimbursement, 25, noMileage));
  } // End else 
} // End summaryOutput
} // End class
```

The program runs fine otherwise.  I just can't figure out the 5 star string.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: how have you attempted to debug this so far? And what have you found?

Comment: I haven't yet.  Since the program ran, I wasnt sure if debugging would help too much.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the keyword `continue` which just skips to the end of the body of the while loop and just continues with the code, so your code should look something like this:

```
if (mileage <= 0) {
    System.out.println("*****");
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Ok.  so would this go in the body of the while loop?

Comment: it would replace the existing if (mileage <= 0) in the while loop, yes